# ANTLR4 sending a null context attribute to listener

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a simple language compiler, and I'm facing an unexpected behavior. I simplified the grammar as follows:

```
grammar Language;

program         : (varDecl)* (funcDecl)* EOF;
varDecl         : type IDENTIFIER ('=' expression)? ';';
funcDecl        : type IDENTIFIER '(' ')' statementBlock;
type            : 'int' # IntType
                ;

statementBlock  : '{' (statement)* '}';
statement       : varDecl ;

expression      : IDENTIFIER '(' (expression (',' expression)*)? ')' # FuncCallExpression
                ;

IDENTIFIER      : ('a'..'z')+;
WHITE_SPACE     : [ \t\u000C\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

As `statementBlock` is a mandatory rule inside the `funcDecl` rule, I would expect that, inside a listener, the `FuncDeclContext` always contains a non-null `funcDecl`. The problem is I'm getting a null `statementBlock` for the following input:

```
int b() {
}
i nt a() {
 int x = b();
}
```

As far as I understand, when facing an invalid input, ANTLR inserts special nodes that represent the expected matching (like the  example from page 163 of the book), but somehow that's not what's happening here (is it a bug?). When I use the following listener, I get "Oh no!":

```
public class DummyListener extends LanguageBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void exitFuncDecl(LanguageParser.FuncDeclContext ctx) {
        super.exitFuncDecl(ctx);

        if (ctx.statementBlock() == null) {
            System.out.println("Oh, no :(");
        }
    }
}
```

What is the reason of this behavior?

**Further investigation**

I discovered an interesting behavior. 
I changed the `funcDecl` rule to include an action:

```
funcDecl        : type IDENTIFIER '(' ')' statementBlock { System.out.println("ID: " + $IDENTIFIER.text + ", text is: " + $statementBlock.text); };
```

and modified exitFuncDecl from the listener to print the identifier too:

```
System.out.println("Listener: id " + ctx.IDENTIFIER().getText());
if (ctx.statementBlock() == null) {
    System.out.println("Oh, no :(");
} else {
    System.out.println("content is " + ctx.statementBlock().getText());
}
```

The output was:

```
line 3:0 extraneous input 'i' expecting {<EOF>, 'int'}
ID: b, text is: {}
line 4:7 mismatched input '=' expecting '('
Listener: id b
content is {}
Listener: id x
Oh, no :(
```

It appears that ANTLR is calling exitFuncDecl but not the rule action. I think the rule action behavior is the right one here, as "x" is causing the null statementBlock. I still don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably related to ANTLR4 Error recovery. I do not know exactly how it works, but from former debugging sessions I know that the Parser:

- inserts expected tokens
- deletes tokens until an expected token occurs

From your error messages it seems probable, that recovery rewrites the token stream as following:

```
int b() {
}
/*deleted: i nt a() {*/
int x /*deleted = b();*/(){
}
```

Yet the insertion of `(){` does not produce a statement block but an error node. So the function declaration will be visitable (although it starts with `int x` instead of `int a`)  but the statement block does not exist (= is an error node).

The recovery strategy maybe documented in the ANTLR4 book, otherwise you will have to debug [DefaultErrorStrategy](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html). You can alter the error strategy if you are not content with this one.

> And why does this happen for listener but not for the rule action?

The action of `funcDecl` is not executed because it has never been parsed, but synthesized by the parsers error recovery. The error recovery cannot take semantic predicates or actions into account.

Now why is the result of the parse a `funcDecl` node, although it is not parsed? The answer is: If a single error break the building of a parent node, then always the top most node of the tree would be an error node. Breaking the complete tree on an error is not common understanding of error recovery.

> I was wondering how should I handle this in my listener code. Checking nulls everywhere?

The listener is the wrong location to handle errors.

**If you want to repair errors:**

Use another error strategy (you can inherit the default strategy and add your code, I have done this once with ANTLR3):

- You could implement it in a way that a broken `funcDecl` is detached
- you could also try to repair it
- you could simply report the error or throw an exception in this case

**If you want to report errors:**

Check if the error strategy has reported errors. If so, then do not apply the visitor an report the errors to the user (possibly rewriting the text to be user friendly). Do not apply the visitor if the parse tree contains errors.

Comment: But why would it insert a "funcDecl" node if it can't make the input match an statementBlock? And why does this happen for listener but not for the rule action?

Comment: Which nodes to insert in an error recovery is a design decision and part of the error recovery. You can alter it to make it more plausible. I add the answer to the other question to my upper posting

Comment: Yes, I understand that it might not take the best decision for this case. What doesn't look quite right to me is that it's recovering with an incomplete node. 
Even then, I asked this on the antlr-discussion group and it seems that's expected. I was wondering how should I handle this in my listener code. Checking nulls everywhere?

Comment: I added answers to my posting

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I was not clear when I asked about the handling in the listener code. Basically, I'm doing semantic error checking using a listener (checking variables are declared and so on). I'm, of course, not trying to correct syntax errors there but I rely on a valid parse tree to be able to extract useful information. 
I'm not using visitors (it would be really error prone and very long for this case), so I think I don't have control over the "listened" nodes directly

Comment: On the other hand, a single error would not turn the parent in an error node. With cases like this, where the top rule has loops, the invalid node could just be ignored and it would be okay (IMHO it would be better).
Now, inheriting from DefaultErrorStrategy and fixing it there is an option, but I have no idea about how to detect if, after the default error correction, the node was left broken. Ideally, I would like to handle this for the general case and not only for funcDecl. Could you point me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: I finally added `if (ctx.exception != null) return;` to most rules. Don't know if there's a better way, but that worked.
Marking as answer